# Consultas con Eloquent

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

¿Cómo puedo hacer una consulta con eloquent usando Like  y relacionarme con otra tabla?-

Lo que pasa es que estoy buscando el perfil de un usuario de acuerdo a sus skills  y especialidad, no sé si ha sido la mejor forma de hacerlo así, pero me funciona. pero hay ciertos datos que me regresa que no tendría que  darme. porque falta una condición más, en Mysql lo haría con  join  y todo perfecto, pero se que eloquent me ofrece algo más elegante. 
Es ahí dónde tengo la duda

porque estoy buscando en la tabla Profile esas  caracteristicas de cada columna, cada perfil  pertenece a una cuenta.

En resumen:   Quisiera mostrar todas las coincidencias de esas columnas de skills y especialidad de la tabla Perfil pero Siempre y cuando  la tabla cuenta en su columna Tipo sea igual  a ='profesor':

Regresandome la información de cuenta con su respectivo perfil.

(Ya tengo mis relaciones, solo me falta la consulta)

Lo tengo de esta forma, pero como he dicho solo me regresa el perfil y no su condición de tipo de cuenta.

```html
  $busqueda = profile::where('skills','LIKE','%'.$tags.'%')
                   ->orWhere('especialidad','LIKE','%'.$tags.'%')
                   ->limit(15)->get();
```

Comment: ¿cómo están definidos los modelos y las relaciones?

Comment: efectivamente, deberias de publicar tus relaciones, para poder ayudarte de mejor forma.

Answer (score 0):

pues lo logre de esta forma:

```html
$busqueda = profile::join('Users','users.id','=','profiles.user_id')
        
                    ->where(function($query) use ($tags){
                       $query->where('profiles.skills','LIKE','%'.$tags.'%')
                       ->orWhere('profiles.especialidad','LIKE','%'.$tags.'%')
                    })
                    ->where('users.role','=','profesor')
                    ->with('user')
                    ->limit(15)
                    ->distinct()
                    ->get();
      

   return view('proyectos.buscar',compact('busqueda'));
```